# Pre-loading/refreshing the page in backend before showing on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if there's a way to refresh/pre-load the CSS of a page before it shows on the browser to a user. Because sometimes we make crucial design changes to our website and the next time we open it the design shows all messed up, until the user refreshes the browser, which then puts the design in the intended positions.

So, what I want is to have a way to refresh a page before it completely loads, so that a user doesn't have to look at a messed up design and doesn't have to leave the site because of such a problem.

Please Help. Appreciated.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cache settings in the browser, you can add unique code/hash of css in the name.
E.g. http://xxx.static.com/1/css.css
When you deploy the next version, it could be http://xxx.static.com/2/css.css.

So that existing pages are not distorted for users as they would be referring the old css with which everything looks fine.

Thanks